# m.cspline in GEKKO breaks when I try to interpolate among decision variables that are being optimized for. Is there a workaround?

Tags: gekko

`m.cspline` throws the following error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'GK_Value'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
\<ipython-input-46-9550efe03532\> in \<cell line: 66\>()
64
65
\---\> 66 \[m.cspline( rhquery\[i\], qstar\[i\], rh_anchor, np.asarray(\[qeq.value for qeq in qstar_anchor\]), bound_x=True) for i in range(npx)\]
67
68 \[m.Equation(q\[i\].dt()==kf\*( qstar\[i\]-\\

\<ipython-input-46-9550efe03532\> in \<listcomp\>(.0)
64
65
\---\> 66 \[m.cspline( rhquery\[i\], qstar\[i\], rh_anchor, np.asarray(\[qeq.value for qeq in qstar_anchor\]), bound_x=True) for i in range(npx)\]
67
68 \[m.Equation(q\[i\].dt()==kf\*( qstar\[i\]-\\

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Here is the Python code:

```py
m = GEKKO()

tf = 9000
npt = 500
xf = L
npx = 10
time = np.linspace(0,tf,npt)
xpos = np.linspace(0,xf,npx)

m.time = time

# create arrays for the state variables
y0= np.zeros((npx))
q0= np.zeros((npx))
qstar0= np.zeros((npx))
rhquery0=np.zeros((npx))


dx = xpos[1]-xpos[0]

#create anchor points in xdata that are fixed
rh_anchor= np.asarray([0, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 95])
#create a naive guess for values at xdata which is the decision variable that has to be optimized for
qstar_anchor0=np.asarray( [(11.69/97.09)*(rh-0) for rh in rh_anchor] )

# define all the simulation constants
dx = m.Const(value = dx)
eps= m.Const(value=eps)
v= m.Const(value=u)
kf= m.Const(value= kf)
yinit= m.Const(value= yinit)
rho_p= m.Const(value =rho_p)
De= m.Const(value=De)

RG=m.Const(value=RG)
T=m.Const(value=Tin)
P_tot=m.Const(value=P_tot)
Psat_in=m.Const(value=Psat_in)


# initial conditions for the state variables
y = [m.Var(value = y0[i]) for i in range(npx)]
q = [m.Var(value = q0[i]) for i in range(npx)]
qstar = [m.Var(value = qstar0[i]) for i in range(npx)]
rhquery = [m.Var(value = rhquery0[i]) for i in range(npx)]

# now define all the qstar decision variables that will be optimized for
qstar_anchor= [m.FV(value = qstar_anchor0[i], lb=0, ub= 11.69) for i in range(len(rh_anchor))]

# define the actual data and the loss to minimize
ytarget = m.Param(value = yData) # this yData is something that I have from a prior expt
m.Minimize((ytarget-y[-1])**2)

# define the ODEs


[m.Equation(rhquery[i]==((y[i]*P_tot)/Psat_in)*100) for i in range(npx)]

for i in range(len(rh_anchor)):
    if i==0:
      m.Equation(qstar_anchor[i]==0)
    else:
      m.Equation(qstar_anchor[i]>= qstar_anchor[i-1])


[m.cspline( rhquery[i], qstar[i], rh_anchor, np.asarray([qeq.value for qeq in qstar_anchor]), bound_x=True) for i in range(npx)]

[m.Equation(q[i].dt()==kf*( qstar[i]-\
                           q[i] ) ) for i in range(npx)]

[m.Equation(y[i].dt()== -u*(y[i+1]-y[i-1])/2/dx+ \
            De* (y[i+1]-2*y[i]+y[i-1])/(dx**2)-\
            rho_p*((1-eps)/eps)*((RG*T)/P_tot)*q[i].dt() ) \
            for i in np.arange(1,npx-1)]

m.Equation(y[0]==yinit  )
m.Equation(y[npx-1]== (4*y[npx-2]-y[npx-3])/3  )



#Application options
m.options.SOLVER = 1  # APOPT MINLP solver
m.options.IMODE = 5   # Dynamic Simultaneous - estimation
m.options.EV_TYPE = 2 # squared error
m.options.NODES = 3   #collocation nodes (2,5)

for i in range(len(rh_anchor)):
  qstar_anchor[i].STATUS=1

m.solve(disp=True)
```

The above code solves for a system of spatially discretized ODEs so that the profile of y at the last spatial grid matches the experimentally obtained data by optimizing for a set of decision variables. Think of the decision variables in this case to be unknown responses, corresponding to fixed points on a certain axis (the `qstar_anchor` and `rh_anchor`, respectively, in the code) that are different from the state variables of the ODE. One would have to interpolate among `rh_anchor` and `qstar_anchor` to find values that plug into the source term, based on the local spatial values of the state variables of a system of ODEs that are being solved for. This is seen to break `m.cspline` on GEKKO. Would greatly appreciate being pointed to a workaround!

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly observed, it isn't possible to make the data elements of a `cspline()` calculated. They must be fixed numbers that are specified during the problem specification such as:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO

# Create a new model
m = GEKKO(remote=False)

# Define the data points
x_data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y_data = [7.3, 5.3, 4.1, 2.0, 1.2]

# Create and solve optimization
x = m.Var(value=2.5,lb=1,ub=5)
y = m.Var()
m.cspline(x, y, x_data, y_data)
m.Minimize((y-3.5)**2)
m.solve(disp=False)

# Result
print(f'Target value y = {y.value[0]} at x = {x.value[0]}')
```

For the problem that you described, it may be possible to take an alternative approach to define the relationship between `rhquery` and `qstar`. One option is to create a polynomial relationship between the two and optimize the coefficients of the polynomial to minimize the objective.

```py
a = m.Array(m.FV,npx,lb=0,ub=10)
b = m.Array(m.FV,npx,lb=0,ub=10)
c = m.Array(m.FV,npx,lb=0,ub=10)
for i in range(npx):
    a[i].STATUS=1
    b[i].STATUS=1
    c[i].STATUS=1
    x = rhquery[i]
    m.Equation(qstar[i]==a[i]*x + b[i]*x**2 + c[i]*x**3)
```

Here is a complete script that solves successfully, but with sample values that may not represent the actual problem.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
L = 1
eps = 1e-3
u = 1
kf = 2.0
yinit = 1.0
rho_p = 1.0
De = 1.0
RG = 1.0
Tin = 300
P_tot = 101325
Psat_in = P_tot

m = GEKKO()

tf = 9000
npt = 50
xf = L
npx = 10
time = np.linspace(0,tf,npt)
xpos = np.linspace(0,xf,npx)

m.time = time

# create arrays for the state variables
y0= np.zeros((npx))
q0= np.zeros((npx))
qstar0= np.zeros((npx))
rhquery0=np.zeros((npx))
yData = np.linspace(0,10,npx)
dx = xpos[1]-xpos[0]

# define all the simulation constants
dx = m.Const(value = dx)
eps= m.Const(value=eps)
v= m.Const(value=u)
kf= m.Const(value= kf)
yinit= m.Const(value= yinit)
rho_p= m.Const(value =rho_p)
De= m.Const(value=De)

RG=m.Const(value=RG)
T=m.Const(value=Tin)
P_tot=m.Const(value=P_tot)
Psat_in=m.Const(value=Psat_in)

# initial conditions for the state variables
y = [m.Var(value = y0[i]) for i in range(npx)]
q = [m.Var(value = q0[i]) for i in range(npx)]
qstar = [m.Var() for i in range(npx)]
rhquery = [m.Var() for i in range(npx)]

# define the actual data and the loss to minimize
ytarget = 5
m.Minimize((ytarget-y[-1])**2)

# define the ODEs
[m.Equation(rhquery[i]==((y[i]*P_tot)/Psat_in)*100) for i in range(npx)]

a = m.Array(m.FV,npx,lb=0,ub=10)
b = m.Array(m.FV,npx,lb=0,ub=10)
c = m.Array(m.FV,npx,lb=0,ub=10)
for i in range(npx):
    a[i].STATUS=1
    b[i].STATUS=1
    c[i].STATUS=1
    x = rhquery[i]
    m.Equation(qstar[i]==a[i]*x + b[i]*x**2 + c[i]*x**3)

[m.Equation(q[i].dt()==kf*( qstar[i]-\
                           q[i] ) ) for i in range(npx)]

[m.Equation(y[i].dt()== -u*(y[i+1]-y[i-1])/2/dx+ \
            De* (y[i+1]-2*y[i]+y[i-1])/(dx**2)-\
            rho_p*((1-eps)/eps)*((RG*T)/P_tot)*q[i].dt() ) \
            for i in np.arange(1,npx-1)]

m.Equation(y[0]==yinit)
m.Equation(y[npx-1]== (4*y[npx-2]-y[npx-3])/3  )

#Application options
m.options.SOLVER = 3  # IPOPT solver
m.options.IMODE = 5   # Dynamic Simultaneous - estimation
m.options.EV_TYPE = 2 # squared error
m.options.NODES = 3   #collocation nodes (2,5)

m.options.COLDSTART=0
m.solve(disp=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, I guess I shall have to manually implement the spline interpolation using the polynomials as indicated by you!